# GQL - Select all parents where specific child is not in children

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, datastore

I'd like to have a parent class (Group) where any number of User may join. I want to display all Groups where the User is not already in. How do I model this data and how do I query? Sorry for not providing any code, but I simply have no idea.

Edit:
In SQL, this would be done with a User table, a Group table and a GroupUser cross ref table. And querying would go:

```
select *
from Group
where Group.ID not in
(
 select GroupID
 from GroupUser
 where UserID = @userid
)
```

Comment: GQL can't do that. (This is also not a parent-child relationship, but that's only a problem with your terminology, and doesn't affect the actual functioning.)

Comment: Well, then please try to look beyond terminology and suggest a solution. This kind of relation is common in reality.

Comment: How many groups do you expect to have? You can store a list of groups for each user and compare it to a list of all of your groups, but this doesn't scale well.

Comment: I see where you're going but as you imply, not suitable because my groups are going to grow into thousands throughout the lifetime of the app. Please, note that User/Group are just kinds I made up for the sake of asking.

Comment: Terminology is important here, because 'child' and 'parent' means specific things about entity relationships in App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I put my question unclearly, I am obviously new to GAE and my terminology may be wrong. Anyway here is my solution:

```
class User(db.Model):
  username = db.StringProperty()

class Group(db.Model):
  users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

To find a group and join (somewhat simplified):

```
groups = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                     "FROM Group")        

for g in groups:                
   if user.key() not in g.users:                    
      group = g
      break

group.users.append(user.key())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be thousands of groups and user is going to be a member of tens of them?

You are going to have a user experience issue: how do you make user choose from thousand of groups? A pagination table with 50+ pages?

About your problem: when you solve the above problem, then you can just properly mark groups user is already a member of:

You can simply have all users groups in memory (it's only ten IDs, right?) and simply filter them as you display the groups.

Comment: Knego, thanks. Never mind the user experience. The Group/User example is just an example. In reality it is the backend that will automatically allocate the users to a "group" where they are not already members. Could you develop your suggested solution with some code example?

Comment: Randomly pick group, if user is not already a member (slim chances as users:groups is 1:1000) add him to the group. If it is a member, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

As Wooble says, there's no way to construct a query like this for the App Engine datastore. If your number of groups greatly outnumbers the number of groups a user is actually in, your best option is just to select all groups, then filter out the ones the user is already in - which is exactly what an SQL database would do given that query.